What's the fix for "This document contains fields that may refer to other files" error with docx from gt table?
I'm trying to generate "error free" docx files of tables using gt and gtsummary.  I'm getting a pop-up window that says "This document contains fields that may refer to other files. Do you want to update the fields in this document?"  I would rather not have the popup window.
I found the error was reproducible in the following example. The first docx files has no popup window while the second docx file does.
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)
library(gtsummary)

trial %>%
  tbl_summary(include = c(age, grade, response)) %>%
  as_gt() %>%
  gtsave("test.docx")



trial %>%
  tbl_summary(include = c(age, grade, response)) %>%
  as_gt() %>%
  tab_header("Title here") %>%
  gtsave("test_title.docx")



The issue is that the second docx contains a caption/header with a table number added as a field. The popup appears for security reasons. For more on this see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60080408/officer-this-document-contains-fields-that-may-refer-to-other-files. A fix would be to use docent::docx_update, i.e. use ... |> gtsave("test_title.docx") |> doconv::docx_update(). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77144136/how-can-i-avoid-the-error-this-document-contains-fields-that-may-refer-to-other

@stefan thanks for the help but unfortunately that didn't work.  I got the error Error: could not update same as link.
